# Sharepoint 2013 - New Field when adding a new Document in Document Library

Tags: document

I am trying to a add a new field in the "new form" when adding a new document in the Standard Document Library. I want to create the field name "Document ID". How do I do this?
[image]

Comment: A ContentType consits of Fields. You can't alter an existing ContentType on the fly. If you want an extra field in a ContentType you have to create your own that inherits the original ConentType and add a new Field.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a content type and add that column to that content type.
Then set that content type to default content type.
In this way it will ask you to fill that filed while uploading .

Comment: There are built in content types "Document" and "ID". How do I set them to default content type?

Comment: Go to library settings -> Advanced settings -> Check allow management of content types. Then in library setting you can set the order of content types.